# Can a lambda in an AWS Step Function know its current Execution Id of AWS Step Function?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

For a lambda executed within a step function, I want to know the current execution id of AWS State Machine within that. Is there a way to know this within the step function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a lambda in an AWS Step Function know the "execution name" of the step function that launched it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854398/can-a-lambda-in-an-aws-step-function-know-the-execution-name-of-the-step-funct)

Answer (score 30):

Old question but the answer is outdated - you can now get this inside the step function - with `$$.Execution.id`. Example I'm using:

```
"run_task": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Parameters": {
    "task.$": "$.task",
    "executionId.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
  },
  "Resource": "${runTaskLambdaArn}",
  "End": true
}
```

Comment: What about passing the execution id to SageMaker batch transform job name? I'm stuck here for a whole morning now, I raised a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609804/how-to-append-stepfunction-execution-id-to-sagemaker-job-names) it would be great if you can take a look, thanks.

Comment: Just a heads up: This returns the ARN of the stepfunction + the execution name. (`arn:name`) which is considered the "id". If only the execution id itself (i.e. the generated id if not manually set) is needed then `$$.Execution.Name` can be used

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AWS Step Functions don't have this feature yet. A common pattern is to define the execution ID (instead of using the auto-generation) and adding it to the input of the execution (from there on, you can use it inside your tasks.

Reference: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=754179