# Access context object when defining a Step Function workflow in the CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I would like to pass in the Step Function Execution ID of the current workflow to my Lambda function when it is executed.

I see in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) that to "access the context object, first specify the parameter name by appending `.$` to the end" however, I cannot do this as I am defining my workflow using the CDK, which does not have access to parameters. I have to use `InputPath`.

---

Despite not being able to follow the instructions I tried a few things anyway. I have tried:

```js
new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, "InvokeLambdaTask", {
  lambdaFunction: myLambda
  inputPath: "$$.Execution.id"
})
```

and got the following error: `Invalid path '$.Execution.id' : No results for path: $['Execution']['id']`

I also tried a single dollar sign:

```js
new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, "InvokeLambdaTask", {
  lambdaFunction: myLambda
  inputPath: "$.Execution.id"
})
```

and got `Invalid path '$.Execution.id' : Missing property in path $['Execution']`

Is there any way to achieve this? I've seen a few [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231691/can-a-lambda-in-an-aws-step-function-know-its-current-execution-id-of-aws-step-f) asking the more or less same thing, however I cannot really make use of these answers using the CDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to pass in the Step Function Execution ID of the current workflow to my Lambda function

The `LambdaInvoke` task's [payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke.html#payload) is supplied to the Lambda function as input.  Note the two equivalent ways of referencing the JSONPath.

```js
new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, "InvokeLambdaTask", {
  lambdaFunction: myLambda,
  payload: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
    executionId: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$$.Execution.Id"),
    "alsoExecutionId.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
  }),
});
```

The Lambda receives the Execution Id in the event payload:

```js
{
    executionId: "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:execution:StateMachine2E01...",
    alsoExecutionId: "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:execution:StateMachine2E01..."
}
```

> The CDK ... does not have access to parameters.

It does.  The CDK renders the `payload` arg into the State Machine definition's `Parameters`:

```json
"Type": "Task",
"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:Lambda...",
"Parameters": {
    "executionId.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
    "alsoExecutionId.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `stepfunctions.JsonPath.stringAt("$$.Execution.id")`. I'm not 100% sure why, but CDK requires you to use `JsonPath.xAt()` for any references.